# Implementing Table specific Audit Trail for postgresql

Tags: postgresql-9.3, audit-trail

I am using postgresql 9.3 and in my application i need to keep audit trail for each table of my schema. Also i need to read and perform some action based on the events recorded in the logs.

Reading few blogs i came to know about some audit trail extension of postgresql, but could not understood how to implement it.
Do i need to upgrade to postgresql 9.4?